# SMS iPhone history chaos after migration from Android

Tags: iphone, messages, android

I used the "Move to iOS" app to transfer data from my old Android phone to a iPhone SE. SMS were transferred but the history is totally chaotic: *Older messages* are displayed *after newer* one and the *timestamp* is *wrong* in *most* of them.

I don't know where to start to solve (if possible) this problem. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Taking a quick look online. This seems to be a fairly common issue. It looks like Apple is recommending to restart both devices and try again. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196

Answer (score 2):

I would reset the whole iPhone and start over. Most likely the file was not read correctly after the transfer from the Android phone and the message history was corrupt/moved.

Look at this [tutorial](https://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/transfer-texts-from-android-to-iphone/) how to transfer messages from *Andriod* to *iPhone*.

Here is the official [document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196) from apple about "Move from Android to iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch".

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar issue, after moving from galaxy s10e to iphone 12.

the messages are all messed up, and the Imessages is supper buggy.

first thing is if I get a message from someone you I received messages in the past- and I click on the notification, then the message I see is months old and not the right one, looks like it the last message I got from that sender before the switch.

to see the new message I need to close the Imessages and enter it once again- then its fine.

another symptom of this would be if I access a message from a sender that sent me messages in the past(before the switch to iphone- for example like the post office), and then switch to another app, or go to home for example, but not exiting the Imessage, and then reopen the Imessages then again I get the issue of seeing the last message from 6 months ago(before the switch to iphone).
and again if I exit the app completely and re enter - its fine.

one more symptom- i'm not sure is entirely related, when I get a message in the Imessages I get double notification- one in the moment of receiving the message and one exactly 2 minutes later.
this behavior happens only with Imessages, and not any other app.